# how to print out how much times it is match the c:if statement

Tags: spring-mvc, jstl

The code I have looks like this:

```
<table border 1>
    <tr>
        <th>Toteutus tunnus</th>
        <th>Toteutus nimi</th>
        <th>Toteutus opettaja</th>
        <th>Palautteen määrä</th>
    </tr>
<c:forEach items="${toteutukset}" var="toteutus">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/palaute/main/toteutuksenpalautteet/${toteutus.toteutusID}">${toteutus.toteutusTunnus}</a></td>
        <td>${toteutus.toteutusNimi}</td>
        <td>${toteutus.opettajaNimi}</td>
        <td>
<c:forEach items="${palautteet}" var="palaute" varStatus="count">
<c:if test="${toteutus.toteutusID == palaute.toteutusID }">

</c:if>
</c:forEach>
        </td>
    </tr>


</c:forEach>
</table>
```

First I print out all things in list courses(toteutus) then I check the list of feedback(palautteet) and then I use c:if to see how many feedback is on each course and I want to display the number of feedbacks next to each course, but I don't know how. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firs suggestion would be to do it in your back-end code, by adding it to the object `toteutus`. Anyway if you want to keep your code you can do something like this:

```
    <td>
       <c:set var="nrOfFeedbacks" value="0" scope="page"/>
       <c:forEach items="${palautteet}" var="palaute" varStatus="count">
         <c:if test="${toteutus.toteutusID == palaute.toteutusID }">
            <c:set var="nrOfFeedbacks" value="${nrOfFeedbacks+ 1}" scope="page"/>
         </c:if>
      </c:forEach>
      //set html for counter
      ${nrOfFeedbacks}
   </td>
```

Comment: Thank You for quick response, but your code doesn't work( Or I might be using in wrong. It shows 0 next to each course even if there is some feedback related to it

Comment: @JavaEvgen Sorry, my bad... variable `nrOfFeedbacks` wasn't incrementing becaues I was setting the new value to `count` (damn copy-paste! :p). Now it works...

Comment: :D Sry was too stupid to fix it myself. I actually noticed that u were increasing another variable, but i just fixed the last line setting "count" to it :D Yeah now it work perfectly. Thank You very much. Btw how do i set that ur answer were the one i needed? :D

Comment: You're welcomed :D (To mark it correct: Theres a faded tick in the left of my answer )